# how to show highest id from table array

Tags: php, mysql

Currently I am using this:

```
<div class="post-detail">
    <?php
        if($_SESSION["ses"]=="")
        {
            $cont="SELECT * FROM content WHERE id < ( SELECT MAX( id ) FROM content) ORDER BY id desc limit 1"; 
            $cont_row=mysql_query($cont);
            $cont_res=mysql_fetch_assoc($cont_row);

    ?>
    <h3 class="post-title"><?php echo $cont_res["page_title"]?></h3>
    <p class="post-description">
        <?php
            echo $cont_res["details"];
        ?>
    </p>
        <?php } ?>
    <div class="read-more">
        <a href="detail.html">Вижте повече...</a>
    </div>
    <div class="sign-up"></div> 
</div>
```

But I would like to show the array with the highest id from table content.
I've already tryed using max but it's not working and giving me some error:

```
<?php
    if($_SESSION["ses"]=="")
    {
        $cont="select * from content  where id='MAX(id)'";
        //echo $cont;
        //exit;
        $cont_row=mysql_query($cont);
        $cont_res=mysql_fetch_assoc($cont_row);
    }

?>
```

This is not working at all. Could someone show the right way of showing the highest id of array in table contents?

Comment: thanks alot this worked!
Is there a way to show the last as you showed me but -1?

Comment: For example I have max 20 id's if I want to show the last one I use your code: $cont="select * from content order by id desc"; but how to show the 19th wich is 20 - 1?

Comment: not working.... it's showing the highest ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best and simplest answer is to sort the data, and then limit the returned values. @shubham did just that in the first line of this answer, and to expand it to cover your comment as well simply use the offset parameter for `limit`
Like this:

```
// Returns the second highest ID (skip 1)
SELECT id, name, data FROM content ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1,1

// Return the top 3
SELECT id, name, data FROM content ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3

// Return sixth to eighth place.
SELECT id, name, data FROM content ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5, 3
```

*Edit: Example from a database:*

```
mysql> select id,created FROM task ORDER by ID DESC limit 1;
+------+---------------------+
| id   | created             |
+------+---------------------+
| 7602 | 2016-09-23 12:28:04 |
+------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select id,created FROM task ORDER by ID DESC limit 1,1;
+------+---------------------+
| id   | created             |
+------+---------------------+
| 7601 | 2016-09-23 10:01:36 |
+------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select id,created FROM task ORDER by ID DESC limit 5,3;
+------+---------------------+
| id   | created             |
+------+---------------------+
| 7597 | 2016-09-22 12:56:49 |
| 7596 | 2016-09-22 12:41:44 |
| 7595 | 2016-09-22 11:22:02 |
+------+---------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

So, as you can see this works.

Comment: Added an example showing that my answer is correct.

Comment: Yes I understand and thanks for your answers but when I type the 3 examples from you in my php page I am getting the same thing wich is the highest ID...

Comment: I can give you teamviewer if you want to see that's not working for me just add me on skype: idivan93

Comment: Do you have many rows with the same ID? If so, then you need to `GROUP BY` the `id` in the query. Though, if this is indeed a primary key for your table, then I suspect you have a badly defined table. ID is normally a unique key, most often an `AUTO_INCREMENT`, which all of the answers given so far have assumed is true in this case too.

Comment: right now I have 4 rows in my content table and the id's are different 1,2,3,4. I don't have rows with same id's...

Comment: and my id is set as primary key

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
SELECT * from content ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

If you only want one such row, then

```
SELECT row from content ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM content WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM content);
```

Comment: SELECT * FROM `content` WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM `content` WHERE id < (SELECT MAX(id) FROM `content`))

Comment: SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM content ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3) AS tbl ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1   and you can replace 3 with any number

Comment: doesn't matter what I am changing it's always showing the highest id

Answer (score 1):

Ifyou want use an aggregation function you  can also filter using having

```
select * from content  having id=MAX(id);
```

Having work on the resulting set ..instead where work on the table row

Comment: but how to display the pre-last id? like I was explaining in the other coments. For example I have table with 3 rows which is id: 1,2 and 3, how can I show the last ID(3) -1?